# is there a way to group by and still show other variables without infringing no-aggregate clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table:

```
id | value
---+-----------
 1 | Monday 
 2 | Tuesday 
 3 | Tuesday 
 4 | Wednesday
```

I need it to display like:

```
value     | count | id1 | id2 
----------+-------+-----+-----
Monday    |  1    |  1  |
Tuesday   |  2    |  2  |  3 
Wednesday |  1    |  4  |
```

**But** using the `Group By` function will not work for obvious reasons ("id" is not contained in either the aggregate function or the `GROUP BY` clause).

However, I still need this done and I have exhausted my knowledge of juggling the variables into temp tables. Need this on SSMS, Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want string aggregation.  Here is a typical method:

```
select value, count(*), string_agg(id, ',') as ids
from t
group by value;
```

If you want the values in two columns, you can use `MIN()` and `MAX()`:

```
select value, count(*),
       min(id) as id1, coalesce(max(id), min(id)) as id2
from t
group by value;
```

Comment: Gordon thank you for your quick feedback. Rethinking my question I see that using an aggregate will not work as I still need variables to be on their own column for later filtering. I have adjusted my question and also specified I am working on SSMS.